# How to replace tr with the last one

Tags: javascript

I want to replace tr clicked with the last tr. I tried replaceWith but it doesn't  work

```
$(this).replaceWith('#table_article tr:last');
```

The context:

```
$('#table_article tr').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  if($(this).attr('id') != undefined){
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url : "{% url 'updateligneFacture_temp' %}",
      data: $("#form_facture").serialize() + "&ref_article=" + $(this).attr('id'),
      success : function(data){
        $('#contenue_fact').html(data);
        $this.replaceWith('#table_article tr:last'); 
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
            },
        error : function(){
             alert("Erreur update !!");
            }
     });
   }
 });
```

Comment: can you please provide some more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all,it s working now,i used the id of the tr clicked

```js
<script>
        $('#table_article tr').on('click', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            if($(this).attr('id') != undefined){
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url : "{% url 'updateligneFacture_temp' %}",
                    data: $("#form_facture").serialize() + "&ref_article=" + $(this).attr('id'),
                    success : function(data){
                        $('#contenue_fact').html(data);
                        $("#"+id).replaceWith($('#table_article tr:last'));// i use id of the tr clicked not object tr
                        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
                    },
                    error : function(){
                        alert("Erreur update !!");
                    }
                });


            }

        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure jQuery is included.

Also, make sure to place a `$` sign before wrapping the selector in parentheses.

```js
$("tr").on("click", function() {
    $(this).replaceWith($("tr:last").html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>$1.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mangos</td>
    <td>$1.20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Oranges</td>
    <td>$1.15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pineapples</td>
    <td>$3.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Docs .replaceWith()

> Replace each element in the set of matched elements with the provided
>   new content

since you are providing a text **'#table_article tr:last'** in your example it must be replacing the clicked row with this text , for replacing with the last row you will have to select the last **tr**  **$('#table_article tr:last')** element and use it in .replaceWith()

```
$(this).replaceWith($('#table_article tr:last'));
```

```js
$("#table_article").on("click", "tr", function() {
  $(this).replaceWith($('#table_article tr:last'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_article">
  <tr>
    <td>First</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.
use this line

```
$(this).html($("tr:last").html());
```

instead of this

```
$(this).replaceWith($("tr:last").html());
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#tableA tr").on("click", function(){
    $(this).html($("tr:last").html());
    })

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%;" border="1px" id="tableA">
    <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>946</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>945</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>924</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>934</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>294</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```